# Use of unresolved identifier 'orientatiorawValue'

Tags: swift

Swift keeps giving me the error typed above. This is the code.

```
static func rotate(orientation:Orientation, clockwise: Bool) -> Orientation {
    var rotated = orientatiorawValue() + (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
    if rotated > Orientation.TwoSeventy.toRaw() {
        rotated = Orientation.Zero.toRaw()
    } else if rotated < 0 {
        rotated = Orientation.TwoSeventy.toRaw()
    }
    return Orientation.fromRaw(rotated)!
}
```

Please be very specific. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: I think you need to add some further information to be specific so that someone can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got halfway transitioned from Swift 1.0 to 1.1 syntax. Wherever you have `.toRaw()` you'll need to switch to `.rawValue`, and then fix this line, too:

```
var rotated = orientation.rawValue + (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
```

Lastly, your return will need to be:

```
return Orientation(rawValue: rotated)!
```